# Connect to GoogleAppEngine's DataStore from local machine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to GoogleAppEngine and facing issues while connecting to GoogleAppEngine's DataStore.

In the tutorial I followed (http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise1.html), we insert into DB and then read. So, it din't help much (I might be missing something).

I have created a table in DataStore and can query the same from Google's UI. Once I try to connect through eclipse (with the same account as my GoogleAppEngine's account) , I am getting following message:

```
INFO: The backing store, /Users/ABC/Documents/workspace/projectABC/war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created.
```

Which in turn returns 0 rows as it has no data.

Code is like this (as mentioned at other places):

```
private static DatastoreServiceConfig config = DatastoreServiceConfig.Builder.withDefaults();
private static DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(config);
```

Jdoconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

   <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
       <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
           value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
   </persistence-manager-factory>


</jdoconfig>
```

How do we convey the datastore to connect to (in my case, I have created it via GUI and inserted some entries into it)? What changes are required?

Do we need to override DefaultServiceConfig? Is `appIdNamespace` required?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [Remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi)?

> The Java SDK includes a library called Remote API that lets you
>   transparently access App Engine services from any Java application.
>   For example, **you can use Remote API to access a production datastore
>   from an app running on your local machine**. You can also use Remote API
>   to access the datastore of one App Engine app from a different App
>   Engine app.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it! Thanks!

Comment: You can also use [Google Cloud Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) to connect to an [existing App Engine application datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_for_an_existing_app_engine_application) from outside App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot connect to the Applications's DataStore which is built in production. :(

It creates a local development datastore and we need to populate/use the same.